# Image Settings Will Not Save

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

Yesterday, I updated my production site from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.8 and have run into a hangup with product images.

1. Uploading photos works (as in they are added to the `/tmp` folder) but they do not show up in the list of images in the admin panel.
2. NONE of my products do not have any of the radio buttons selected for the Base Image, Small Image, Thumbnail settings -- and when I try to set them, the page refreshes but the radios are still not selected. Weird. (screenshot)

My staging site (same version of Magento) has not of the issues above. Which makes me think it could be db related.
[image: No radios saving]